# How do I make a program that gets a letter from the user and outputs something according to the letter?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Let me tell you more about this question:
So, I want to make a program that gets a letter from the user and according to the letter, if it is "R", outputs "It's Red!" in Red text, if it is "G", outputs "It's Green!" in Green text if it is "B", outputs "It's Blue!" in Blue text! But if it is not R, G, or B, then outputs that there is no color associated with this letter.
It is a C# Console App and this is what I've written for now:

```
            char color;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter (R/G/B): ");
            color = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if(color==R)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("It's Red!");
            }

            else if(color==G)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("It's Green!");
            }

            else if (color==B)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("It's Blue!");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

One more thing to mention is that I don't know how to write that other part where how to make it if "color" doesn't match R or G or B. I would be happy to know how to do that as well
It is just a little program I'm making out of boredom.

I tried to make something that if "color" is R, outputs that. But I'm not sure how to do that so any assistance regarding that would be great!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Have you declared the R, G, B identifiers you are using in your code somewhere in your project? Because the code in your question doesn't show whether and how you have declared them, leaving us in the unenviable situation to be only able to speculate about your problem instead of you telling us what exactly the problem is that you encountered/observed ...

Comment: add `else { your code}` after the last `else if` statement. also do you want text or background in red for `R` ?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I did not use the identifiers in my code.

Comment: @viveknuna Yes.

Comment: @KianmehrK. what do you mean by yes? Be clear

Comment: @KianmehrK. "_I did not use the identifiers in my code_." No? Then you do not have `R`, `G` and `B` right there in your source code trying to compare them against `color`? I guess i must be hallucinating then...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Sorry, I meant yes, I used it (I'm doing too many things at once now so I'm a bit messed up)

Answer (score 2):

The following code should do the trick:

```
char color;

Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter (R/G/B): ");
color = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if(color=='R')
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("It's Red!");
}

else if(color=='G')
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("It's Green!");
}

else if (color=='B')
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("It's Blue!");
}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("There is no color associated with this letter!");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an dictionary (key,value) where `key` is the letter, and `value` is the message.

You create it like so  `var dic = new Dictionary<char, string>();`

And use it like so:

```cs
//dic.Add("key","Value");
  var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  dic.Add("R","It's Red!");
  dic.Add("G","It's Green!");
  dic.Add("B)","It's Blue!");
  //use .ToUpper() if the key is uppercase in order to ensure its not case sensetive
  if(dic.TryGetValue(color.ToUpper(),out var message))
  {
    //output message
    Console.WriteLine(message);
  }
  else
  {
    //output errormessag
  }
```

You can add as many key/value as you want for each letter

Answer (score 0):

Here's some tips on improving your code.  When you have repetitive code that looks like:

```
if(color==R)
{
    /* block of code */
}
else if(color==G)
{
    /* block of code */
}
else if (color==B)
{
    /* block of code */
}
else 
{
    /* block of code */
}
```

You might want to consider using a `switch` statement.  But, that's not what I'm going to suggest.

Instead, I'm going to concentrate on your

```
    /* block of code */
```

The same code is repeated in each block:

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("It's Red!");
```

We folks in the software business love three letter acronyms.  One of the ones you will here is the *DRY Principle*.  In this case *DRY* stands for *Don't repeat yourself*.  You are repeating your self in each block.  If you decide to do something different, you'll need to update each of those blocks with the change.

Instead of this repetition, let's look at the code.  There are three pieces of data that could represent what each block means:

1. BackgroundColor
2. ForegroundColor
3. Message to write out

So, let's create a class that represents that data:

```
public class MessageAndFormat
{
    public ConsoleColor Foreground { get; set; }
    public ConsoleColor Background { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

It's a simple class that has three properties.  Now, let's write a method that consumes the data from a `MessageAndFormat` class instance:

```
public static void WriteMessageAndFormat(MessageAndFormat messageAndFormat)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = messageAndFormat.Foreground;
    Console.BackgroundColor = messageAndFormat.Background;
    Console.WriteLine(messageAndFormat.Message);
}
```

Instead of keying on a `char`, I'm going to do it on a single character `string`.  The framework has endowed strings with more capabilities; in particular, you can do case-independent comparisons of strings (and I don't think you can with simple chars)

Instead of using if/then/else or using a switch statement, I'm going to use a `Dictionary` for my "what character - what action" logic.  So, I'm going to declare and initialize that dictionary:

```
 private static Dictionary<string, MessageAndFormat> colorMapping = new Dictionary<string, MessageAndFormat>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
 {
     {"R", new(){Background = ConsoleColor.Black, Foreground = ConsoleColor.Red, Message = "It's Red!"} },
     {"G", new(){Background = ConsoleColor.Black, Foreground = ConsoleColor.Green, Message = "It's Green!"} },
     {"B", new(){Background = ConsoleColor.White, Foreground = ConsoleColor.Blue, Message = "It's Blue!"} },
 };
```

Now I have the core of my logic encapsulated in an easy to read declarative data structure.  The `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` parameter to the dictionary constructor says "use case-ignoring logic when checking the key of this dictionary".  As a result, a key of `"r"` will be treated the same as a key of `"R"`.

When I was writing this code, I realized that it would be useful to let the user know that he/she had typed an unknown character.  I also realized it would be nice to let the user know the program was quitting.  So I declared and initialized these two variables as well:

```
private static MessageAndFormat Unknown = new() { Background = ConsoleColor.Gray, Foreground = ConsoleColor.White, Message = "Unknown" };
private static MessageAndFormat Quitting = new() { Background = ConsoleColor.Black, Foreground = ConsoleColor.White, Message = "Quitting" };
```

I changed up your program a bit.  Now it runs forever, until the user types `"Q"` (to quit).

```
public static void Test()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type R/G/B for a color or Q to quit");
    while (true)
    {
        string typedChar = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar.ToString();
        if (string.Equals(typedChar, "Q", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            break;  //quit the program
        }

        if (colorMapping.TryGetValue(typedChar, out var messageAndFormat))
        {
            WriteMessageAndFormat(messageAndFormat);
        }
        else
        {
            WriteMessageAndFormat(Unknown);
        }
    }
    WriteMessageAndFormat(Quitting);
}
```

A few things to note:

This line reads a key typed (not a line of text).

```
string typedChar = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar.ToString();
```

The `ReadKey` call returns a bunch of information about what is typed.  The `KeyChar` property gets the key as a `char`, which I turn into a single char `string` with `ToString`.  The `true` parameter to the `ReadKey` call causes the key to be read, but not echoed to the console.  Instead, when the user types `R`, he/she will simply see `It's Red!`

This line:

```
colorMapping.TryGetValue(typedChar, out var messageAndFormat)
```

Tries to get the `MessageAndFormat` value that corresponds to the typed character.  If there's a match, it returns `true`.  If there is no match, it returns `false`.  The `TryGet_Something_` pattern is pretty common in C# code.

If I start up the program and type "RGBXQ", I'll get this at the console (with each line in the appropriate colors:

```
Type R/G/B for a color or Q to quit
It's Red!
It's Green!
It's Blue!
Unknown
Quitting
```